# Using string formatting to evaluate hexadecimal, binary, decimal and octal versions of a value

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner at Python, attempting to understand how string formatting can help in listing the hexadecimal, octal, decimal, and binary versions of a number all in one line.

I am attempting to understand the logic of the code snippet provided.

```py
"{0:{width}d} {0:{width}o} {0:{width}X} {0:{width}b}".format(i,width = width)
```

I do not understand how the above code works. Mainly:

- what is the function of 0:
- what is the function of {width} (is it for spacing)
- what are `d`, `o`, `X`, and `b` and how are they being evaluated.

Apologies for the lengthy question, I am a beginner and I did not seem to understand any other explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get to know what a piece of code does is to execute it in a Python interpreter when appropriate ([see this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) if you don't know how the interpreter works). In this case, I suggest that you start by simply running that line and see what happens.

```
>>> "{0:{width}d} {0:{width}o} {0:{width}X} {0:{width}b}".format(i,width = width)
...
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

First, you notice a name error, which means the variable `i` is not assigned. Let's change it then to say, 42.

```
>>> "{0:{width}d} {0:{width}o} {0:{width}X} {0:{width}b}".format(42,width = width)
...
NameError: name 'width' is not defined
```

Of course, we also need to indicate what `width` is. Let's try with the value `8`.

```
>>> "{0:{width}d} {0:{width}o} {0:{width}X} {0:{width}b}".format(42,width = 8)
'      42       52       2A   101010'
```

Now we get something that seems to work. What is `width`, then? You can see it affects the spacing to the left of the different values that you get. Let's try changing it to `14`.

```
>>> "{0:{width}d} {0:{width}o} {0:{width}X} {0:{width}b}".format(42,width = 14)
'            42             52             2A         101010'
```

The space has indeed increased. Now, based on the title of your question, I will assume that you know what hexadecimal, binary, decimal and octal numbers are. As a *very* short refresher, just know that:

- Decimal is base 10 (using numbers from 0 to 9, adding 1 and starting again when reaching the next value → ... 8, 9, 10, 11...).
- Binary is base 2 (using numbers from 0 to 1, adding 1 and starting again when reaching the next value → 0, 1, 10, 11, 100...).
- Hexadecimal is base 16 (using numbers from 0 to 9 and letters from A to F to form numbers of value from 0 to 15, adding an additional digit adds 16 → ... 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, 10, 11...).
- Octal is base 8 (using numbers from 0 to 7, adding a digit each time we reach 7 → ... 6, 7, 10, 11, 12...).

Where you might be wondering is: why does 0 (zero) appear at the beginning of each number representation? This is part of what is called **string formatting** as you mentioned. You will find more information on the subject in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). What this means here is that every time you have `0` in curly braces in a string, the first value passed to the `.format()` function (in this case, `42`), will replace `0` and a format will be applied to it.

Here is an example of how it works. You don't have to limit yourself to using `0`. In fact, you can have other numbers like so:

```
>>> "{0} is a number, {1} is another number and {0} is the same as the first number.".format(12, 24)
'12 is a number, 24 is another number and 12 is the same as the first number.'
```

You could even skip numbers entirely inside the curly braces if you only have one value:

```
>>> "{} is a number.".format(12)
'12 is a number.'
```

To understand the right side in the curly braces, after the colon, you will need to check out the documentation I referenced earlier. But as a quick start, suppose you want to display a floating number with 2 decimal places. You would say `.2` for a precision of 2 digits and `f` to indicate `float`. This would look like:

```
>>> "{0:.2f} is a number.".format(12)
'12.00 is a number.'
```

In your particular example, `d` stands for **decimal**, `o` stands for **octal**, `X` stands for **heXadecimal** and `b` stands for **binary**. You can see this is true because in the example given with `42`, `42` is indeed `42` in decimal, `52` in octal, `2A` in hexadecimal and `101010` in binary.